# Drupal 8 Create XML Queue

Tags: php, xml, drupal, queue

I'm wondering how I would go about creating an XML file of roughly 17,000 entities with the Drupal 8 Queue.

I have tried batch processing and it takes forever, slows down the site, and most of the time fails.

Thanks!

Comment: Where is that 17000 coming from? Is it a database table or ...?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own `QueueWorker` plugin. A tutorial can be found at https://www.crabsoul.org/blog/drupal-8-queue-api-using-cron-and-manual-callback-handler for example. To sum up:

1. In the directory modulename/src/Plugin/QueueWorker directory create a file called XmlCreator.php
2. The contents should be a `class XmlCreator extends QueueWorkerBase` with a `@QueueWorker` class annotation.
3. You should implement the `function processItem($data)` method.

Like so:

```
namespace Drupal\modulename\Plugin\QueueWorker;

use Drupal\Core\Queue\QueueWorkerBase;

/**
 *
 * @QueueWorker(
 * id = "xml_creator",
 * title = "XML Creator",
 * )
 */
class XmlCreator extends QueueWorkerBase {

  public function processItem($data) {
```

Each such should create one part of the XML file, write it into an approriate file and later you could just concat them and wrap them in the root element.

`processItem` will be called for each row in the `{queue}` table with whatever serialized data is in the `data` column. So the question as asked can't be answered for we would need to know what is the source you want to process. If it happens to be an integer in some table, I can offer you an actual, production deployed update function which populated a queue with a ginormous amount of entries in a fraction of a second:

```
function sd8_update_8046() {
  $db = \Drupal::database();
  $select = $db->select('file_managed');
  $select->addExpression(':name', 'name', [':name' => 'sd8_image_style_regenerate']);
  // the following line is the interesting part.
  $select->addExpression('CONCAT(:prefix, fid, :suffix)', 'data', [':prefix' => 'i:', ':suffix' => ';']);
  $select->addExpression('UNIX_TIMESTAMP()', 'created');
  $select->condition('filemime', 'image/%', 'LIKE');
  $select->condition('created', 1561964400, '>');
  $select->condition('uri', 'public%', 'LIKE');
  $insert = $db->insert('queue');
  $insert->fields(['name', 'data', 'created']);
  $insert->from($select);
  $insert->execute();
}
```

Should you have a different source of truth, you need to adjust accordingly but in general, you want to bypass the `DatabaseQueue` and use `DatabaseQueue::doCreateItem` more as a pattern of what Drupal expects in the `queue` table. You might want to write a batch / multipart update which does an insert with a few hundred values (`Insert` supports multiple `value()` calls) and so run only like 90 `INSERT () VALUES (), ..., ()` commands or the DBTNG equivalent of that. Or an `INSERT ... SELECT` as shown above. Running 18 000 separate INSERT commands is not conducive to success.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it.